# Add renderings for all specific folder items using PS

Tags: sitecore-query, powershell

We have a following structure :

```
master:/content/market1/myfolder
master:/content/market2/myfolder
master:/content/market3/myfolder
```

etc.

I would like to add renderings for all items within "myfolder" and also for all markets using PowerShell script (there is like 15 items in myfolder and also like 20 markets, so nobody wants to do it manually).

I am pretty new here. Did someone experienced something like this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want just to copy items from one folder into another folder?

Comment: no i just want to add renderings for all items in "myfolder". I have created rendering which i want to add to all items,

Comment: did you created rendering  on standard values or are totally different renderings for every item?

Comment: it is the same rendering for all items. I have created one , which is controller rendering. But i want to add it for all items (not manually)

Comment: You will need a specific placeholder so as to know where to add the new rendering.

Comment: Placeholder can be "whatever" in this case. So only thing is to automatize these steps : click on item > presentation > details > add my rendering > fill "whatever" to placeholder. And this needs to be done for all items in "myfolder" and for all markets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below script to add rendering to the items.

```
$containerArray = @("{Sitecore Id goes here}","{Sitecore Id goes here}","{Sitecore Id goes here}")

foreach ($element in $containerArray){
    $items = Get-ChildItem -ID $element.ID -Language "en"

    $addedRendering = Get-Item "master:path to your rendering goes here" | New-Rendering -Placeholder "contentMain" 

    foreach($item in $items){
        Write-Host "Processing item: " $item.Name
        Add-Rendering -Item $item -PlaceHolder "contentMain" -Rendering $renderingItem
    }
}
```

**Note**

1. Replace the `{Sitecore Id goes here}` with the Id of the containers.
2. You can change the language if required.
3. You need to specify the name of the placeholder so that it knows where to add the rendering.